# endpointscfg.py returning TypeError when app uses endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

When I run
endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs grandle x.apis.app

I get
TypeError: x.apis.app is not a ProtoRPC service

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Was not calling it with the full path to the api class.  Apparently you need to call EACH class, this is not as helpful as I thought it would be.